# How to display the value of a function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and am finding it difficult to make sense of it. I'm trying to understand someone else's code by testing out a function but cannot figure out how to do this. The function is below:

```
same_ratio_dec_inf a b c d e f g h =
case z_eq_dec (zmult a f) (zmult b e) of
LLeft ->
  (case z_eq_dec (zmult b g) (zmult c f) of
     LLeft ->
       (case z_eq_dec (zmult c h) (zmult d g) of
          LLeft ->
            (case z_eq_dec (zmult a g) (zmult c e) of
               LLeft ->
                 (case z_eq_dec (zmult a h) (zmult d e) of
                    LLeft -> z_eq_dec (zmult b h) (zmult d f)
                    RRight -> RRight)
               RRight -> RRight)
          RRight -> RRight)
     RRight -> RRight)
RRight -> RRight
```

If I ":t same_ratio_dec_inf" I get:

```
same_ratio_dec_inf :: Z -> Z -> Z -> Z -> Z -> Z -> Z -> Z -> Sumbool
```

Sumbool is defined earlier as follows:

data Sumbool = LLeft
               | RRight

I see some other code where Z inputs are given as follows:

```
showQ  (qquadratic (toZ a) (toZ b) (toZ c) (toZ d) (toZ e) (toZ f) (toZ g) (toZ h) (toQ x) (toQ y))
```

So I think I can give the function the right inputs...it's just unclear to me how to generate and show the output.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!!

edit: the entire code can be found here: https://github.com/coq-contribs/qarith-stern-brocot/blob/master/quadratic.hs

Comment: Haskell is a very type-oriented language.  The answers to your questions almost entirely come from the types involved.  Could you please include the type of  `zmult`, and the definition of the type `Z` and everything it depends on?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, that staircase pattern almost always means the function should be rewritten with some sort of helper.  This looks like it should be rewritten with a helper function like `combine :: Sumbool -> Sumbool -> Sumbool ; combine RRight _ = RRight ; combine _ x = x` and `foldr1 combine`.

Comment: If you're trying to understand this person's code because you have to, that's fine. But if you're trying to understand it for educational purposes, delete this code, empty your recycle bin, and then go find better code to decipher.

Comment: Hi Carl, please check out the following link for the entire code. Hopefully this makes it easier for you to provide advice. By the way, this code was exported from Coq. Thanks!!!  https://github.com/coq-contribs/qarith-stern-brocot/blob/master/quadratic.hs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear what you are confused about, but I tried something. Maybe it helps.

In your link (https://github.com/coq-contribs/qarith-stern-brocot/blob/master/quadratic.hs) there's some usages of `qquadratic_`:

```
lazy_plus_ x y = qquadratic_  0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 x y
lazy_mult_ x y = qquadratic_  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 x y
...
```

I wondered the expected type of `x` `y`, so I:

```
*Quadratic> :t qquadratic_
qquadratic_
:: (Integral a, Integral a1, Integral a2, Integral a3, Integral a4,
    Integral a5, Integral a6, Integral a7) =>
    a
    -> a1
    -> a2
    -> a3
    -> a4
    -> a5
    -> a6
    -> a7
    -> [Char]
    -> [Char]
    -> [Char]
```

We get: 1. `x` and `y` are strings (of some desired format) 2. `qquadratic_` will return string eventually (so is `lazy_plus_`, `lazy_mult_`, ...), making it easy to see the output.

Then I tried to construct some `x` and `y`. They are fed to `toQ`, and according to the definition of `toQ`,

```
toQPos "I"= One
toQPos "" = One
toQPos ('L':xs) = (DL (toQPos xs))
toQPos ('R':xs) = (NR (toQPos xs))

toQ "0"= Zero
toQ ('-':xs) = (Qneg (toQPos xs))
toQ ('+':xs) = (Qpos (toQPos xs))
toQ (x:xs) = (Qpos (toQPos (x:xs)))
```

I guessed some inputs:

```
*Quadratic> lazy_plus_ "0" "0"
"0"
*Quadratic> lazy_plus_ "+R" "+I"
"RR"
```

If you know what the original Coq program does, you may come up with some meaningful inputs.

Comment: Hi SnowOnion, thanks for taking a look at the code and providing a response! I'm still not clear on how I can print the output of same_ratio_dec_inf. I see it is expecting 8 arguments, which I think I can specify by entering 8 integers and using the toZ function to convert them to the expected input format. But I'm not sure what I need to do print the output. If you've got any ideas, that would be great. Thanks again!

Comment: @RyanO'Connor At line 46, change `data Sumbool = LLeft | RRight` to `data Sumbool = LLeft | RRight deriving Show`. It makes type `Sumbool` an instance of typeclass `Show` and automatically generates a default implementation of `show :: Sumbool -> String`, hence values of type `Sumbool` become printable.

Comment: @RyanO'Connor haha I can [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) finally :)